# Why does useRouter() and router parameters not work in my Nuxt project

Tags: routes, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a file in pages/products called [id].vue and my code in it is

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Hello {{ id }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const { id } = useRoute().params

</script>

<style  scoped>

</style>
```

So when I open localhost:3000/products/123 I should land on a page which says Hello 123 but I land on a 404 page instead.
I also doesnt get the useRoute function suggested in code as if it doesnt exist. Do I have to install/add it extra?

My normal routes work just fine.

I followed this tutorial
I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS8MwC8S4o8&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9haQlqdCQyYmL_27TesCGPC&index=5

My nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'meineSeite',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
  ],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

my Projekt structure:

```
.nuxt
components
    Main.vue
    NuxtLogo.vue
nodemodules
pages
    products
        [id].vue
        index.vue
    index.vue
static
store
.editorconfig
.gitignore
nuxt.config.js
package-lock.json
package.json
README.md
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: have you try rebuild your project?

Comment: Please share your project structure and your `nuxt.config.js` file.

Comment: @Jazuly Yes I tried that but it didnt work.

Comment: @Erik your nuxt.config.js is in Nuxt 2 format. Update it in Nuxt 3 format: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/configuration Other then that, the param should just work.

Comment: Yes I made the Mistake of using Nuxt 2. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a bit like you are using Nuxt 2, buildModules for example is deprecated in Nuxt 3. You have to update to Nuxt 3 for useRoute and to follow this guide.